# kotlin startswith not working as expected. Filter not matching

Tags: android, kotlin, startswith

I use startsWith to match "in" but it matches other Strings too. See attached screenshot of a debug session where "LGRX" matches

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's weird! What happens if you try:

```
aircraft.location.substring(0,2) == "in"
```

Still returns true?

Comment: Still returns true

Comment: Maybe, it's overwritten somehow. Could you share all function with the data you receive?